# Remove multiple spaces

Tags: c++, string, spacing

What I have right now works if there is only 2 spaces. But any more then two spaces and it doesn't get rid of all the spaces. What would be the best way for me to repeat this process over until there is only 1 space?

```
void removeExtraSpaces(string& sentence){
  int i;
  i = sentence.find("  ");
  string t;
  if (i > -1)
  {
    t = sentence.replace(i,2," ");
    removeExtraSpaces(t);
  }   
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to reduce multiple consecutive spaces to a single space?

Comment: Yes, I want to reduce everything to single spacing. This works if the string only has a 2 space gap between words any more then that and it doesn't fix all of it. I feel that a for statement could fix my problem? To just repeat this process until everything is down to one space. But I cant seem to come up with a loop that would work for this.

Comment: In the duplicate linked by Doorknob, be sure to look at the second answer (by Cubbi).  It is, in my opinion, much better than the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm a little lost on what he did exactly. I've only been doing c++ for a few months now. But my big concern is we haven't gone over most of the programming he is using. I think I might get docked if I use something so much farther ahead of us.

Comment: @Snobbysteven he's using a standard library function that is essentially designed to do *exactly* what you want; remove duplicate entries. The version he's using accepts a third parameter that is an object supporting a function-call operator (`operator ()(params..)`) designed to allow you to specify a single character of which to consider duplicates. This prevents the algorithm from turning `bookkeeper` into `bokeper`, but instead only considers duplicates of the specific char (a space in this case). Honestly, the idea is not just proper; its *perfect*.